# How do I clear the printer queue in Completed Jobs section?

Tags: printer

Just successfully printed a bunch of documents but I don't see how to clear these completed jobs. Tried highlighting a job and then "delete" key, right-click, double-click. No response.

Thanks!

Comment: My job lists blanked when I deleted the contents of `/var/spool/cu` I had nothing precious to lose and had first deleted a second printer experiment, and this cleared the completed jobs on my single remaining printer.

Comment: edit fail: `/var/spool/cups` but will need admin permissions to delete the contents